# C# Build JSON payload - List in List

Tags: c#, json.net, swagger, restsharp

I have huge problems with building an JSON-payload.
Hopefully, someone can give me a push in the right direction.
With PostMan it's easy to CRUD-Articles, with C# i'm struggling here.

The ***UomUnitPrices*** makes me headache.

First of all, i need to do it in

- .Net35
- RestSharp 105.2.3.0
- Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.0.0

I'm struggeling with List in List's

```
{
    "Id": "10006",
    "Barcodes": [
        {
            "Barcode": "1010006"
        }
    ],
    "UomUnitPrices": [
        {
            "Prices": [
                {
                    "PriceLevelId": "1",
                    "PriceValue": 5.000
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

***The payload i should create, looks like this:***

```
{
    "Id": "10006",
    "Barcodes": [
        {
            "Barcode": "1010006"
        }
    ],
    "UomUnitPrices": [
        {
            "Prices": [
                {
                    "PriceLevelId": "1",
                    "PriceValue": 5.000
                },
                {
                    "PriceLevelId": "100",
                    "PriceValue": 20.000
                },
                {
                    "PriceLevelId": "200",
                    "PriceValue": 10.000
                },
                {
                    "PriceLevelId": "300",
                    "PriceValue": 15.000
                },
                {
                    "PriceLevelId": "400",
                    "PriceValue": 17.500
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Description": "Article Description",
    "GroupAId": "50",
    "VisibilityCriteriaId": "1",
    "IsValid": true,
    "MeasureUnitId": "pcs",
    "Vat1Id": "1",
    "Vat2Id": "2"
}
```

**All works, except the "UomUnitPrices"-List with the "Prices"-List in it.**

```
public partial class ArticlesDTO
{
    ...
    [JsonProperty("UomUnitPrices")]
    public List<UomUnitPrice> UomUnitPrices { get; set; }
    ...
}

public partial class UomUnitPrice
{
    [JsonProperty("Prices")]
    public IList<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

public partial class Price
{
    [JsonProperty("PriceLevelId")]
    public string PriceLevelId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PriceValue")]
    public double PriceValue { get; set; }
}

public partial class ArticlesDTO
{
     public ArticlesDTO CreateArticle(string id, string description, string groupAid, bool isValid, string measureUnitId, string vat1Id, string vat2Id)
    {
        Barcode barcode = new Barcode().CreateBarcode("String Barcode");
        UomUnitPrice uomUnitPrice = new UomUnitPrice().UomUnitPriceList(); //Here i need a solution

        ArticlesDTO article = new ArticlesDTO()
        {
            Id = id,
            Description = description,
            GroupAId = groupAid,
            VisibilityCriteriaId = 1,
            IsValid = true,
            MeasureUnitId = measureUnitId,
            Vat1Id = vat1Id,
            Vat2Id = vat2Id,
            Barcodes = new List<Barcode>() { barcode },
            UomUnitPrices = new List<UomUnitPrice>() { uomUnitPrice } // That can't be that hard...
        };
        return article;
    }
    public ArticlesDTO CreateArticle(DataRow dataRow)...
}
```

Can somebody give me an advice how to solve that problem.

It's so humbling that I can't solve the problem myself.
I watched several youtube/udemy -videos, read a lot on stackoverflow ([especially this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546287/how-to-create-a-complex-json-object-using-c-sharp)), but it wouldn't solve my problem.

Finally i would create the "Articles"-JSON-payload with a System.Data.DataRow.
But as long as I can't even create that payload, it's going to be a long road to get there.

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Comment: https://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score -1):

Try to switch your Prices type to only List instead of IList

Comment: this could go in a comment instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).